# Eclipse debugger does not recognize new java code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have added new method to my javacode and put breakpoint at the begin of this method and different places. Eclipse debugger go throw the breakpoints in the old code but not in the new added method. I have cleared my project project-> clear to exclude the cache possibility. for me, it appears that eclipse dont recognize the new added Java code.

Any Idea what could be the problem? I use eclipse Juno Service Release 2.

Comment: Obvious question, but do you even call this new method ?

Comment: Well, then I can't help you sir. Hopefully you will find out.

Comment: @Arty: sure i did. The debugger pointer jump to empty space, where is no code :(

Comment: did you compile your code with the new method in it. until you compile and redeploy debugger will not recognize new code

Comment: Can you show us the part the method is called and the code of the method? maybe you open a new thread or something and you wont jump to the breakpoint because you are in a different thread and the method is never called in the one you´ve joined.

Comment: Many possibilities..Hot code replacement doest work as **Class signature** is changed. Terminate old debug session, clean, build, start new debug session. Check whether the new method parent method is getting called and its parent? ............................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop debugging and start the program again since the signature has changed. If you want more hot-swap possibilities you need to consider using [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) or similar tool.