# Eclipse does not run incremental build

Tags: java, eclipse, jrebel, redeploy

I am using Eclipse Galileo, JRebel for hot deploy and JBoss 5.1.x as application server. Recently Eclipse is started behaving weird, may be after switching to a new workspace(only difference is from branch to trunk).

Previously whenever I make a change in a `*.java`/`*.jsp` file, JRebel picks up the newly changed `.class` file to hot deploy.

But now it runs the Full build instead of incremental build, all projects get built instead of one .class update and takes a long time. Server crashes down sometimes due to JRebel trying to deploy all updated `*.class` files.

Does anyone have idea why Eclipse runs full build instead of incremental build while saving the file ?

Comment: Are you truly only saving one file? Could you be refactoring? That will change potentially many files at once.

Comment: No. Just updating one file at a time, like introducing simple changes to code.

Comment: For JRebel, you may use a workaround by adding -Drebel.check_class_hash=true VM argument to the application run configuration, so that it would check if the class really changed, and not only the timestamp of the class file.

Comment: I would really need to see Eclipse not building the whole workspace which takes a while due to the size. But I hope this solution saves my JRebel crashing from numerous reload of class files. Thanks anyway !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Builders to Project in Eclipse and Incremental-ness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434400/adding-builders-to-project-in-eclipse-and-incremental-ness)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse debugger does not recognize new java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862253/eclipse-debugger-does-not-recognize-new-java-code)